# Java Priority Queue with Efficient delete(...) (or update)

Tags: java, queue

I am developing an event driven simulator and my events are all in a java.util.PriorityQueue. The problem is that the events get rescheduled a lot during runtime and since there is no updating of priorities in the stock PriorityQueue, I remove the elements and re-insert them with the new priority.

This works but the performance is (too) bad and it doesn't scale well. JVisualVM's profiler tells me that 99 % of the time gets wasted in pq.delete(...).

Is there an implementation of a PQ with efficient updating of priorities or at least one where the delete(...) is more efficient than the O(N) from the stock one?

I tried a Fibonacci heap which works a lot faster up to a certain point but doesn't scale well either.

Comment: Approx how many updates are you expecting per element versus polling? As in, how many times do you think an element's priority will be changed before it is polled, on average?

Comment: Many, many times. As in, tens to hundreds, I believe.

Comment: How does that compare to your expected size of the heap? If it's a constant factor of the size, it may be faster to forget heaps entirely and just use a hashmap of priorities. That will give you O(1) update and O(N) pollMin/pollMax. Up to you if that's faster

Comment: May be try to use TreeSet or TreeMap instead of PriorityQueue?

Comment: I will try that, Mshnik, and come back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: I will also look into TreeSet and TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a queue solution: Do not remove from a queue but maintain a separate queue. Whenever you need to shuffle priorities you just form a new queue and replace the original one with it.

To avoid potential concurrency issues you should block readers/writers at a certain point to reassign the queue.